# Making a parser in Java

Tags: java, parser, r

I am making a parser for Turtle and I am done with it, but the problem is that it is awful. I'm not allowed to use global variables or parameters which is why it is more complicated that it needed to be. My program right now doesn't take care of all errors. I have keywords/tokens like forward, back, left, right, period, quote, repeat etc... We use repeat in this form.

Repeat 2 Forward 10. or Repeat 2 "Forward 10."

or

Repeat 2 "Forward 10. Left 45."

or

Repeat 2 Repeat 2 Forward 10.

Given: Repeat 2 "Forward 10. Left 45."

I was gonna explain my code but it got way complicated, can anyone give me advice on how to keep track of my quotes. Because given a nested quotes, the program gets a little too dumb. I have exceptions I throw but that only works for none nested expression. I know it is hard for you guys to help me given this little information but I'd appreciate any type of type of tips.